# Sails.js Waterline query modifiers for dates with sails-mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I just started using Sails.js with its ORM, Waterline, and absolutely love it, but I am not sure how to use query modifiers for dates. I am using sails-mysql. Specifically, I am trying to get rows that have a datetime field between two specific dates. I have tried doing this:

```
MyModel.find()
    .where({ datetime_field: { '>=': startDate } })
    .where({ datetime_field: { '<=': endDate } })
    .done(function(err, objects){
        // ...
    });
```

`startDate` and `endDate` are two `Date` objects. I have also tried converting them to strings with `toString()`. In both cases, I get every row from the database instead of rows between the two dates. Is there a way to do this or is this functionality not yet part of either Waterline or sails-mysql?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the same boat (no pun intended) but using sails-mongo.

Provided you have the correct date formatting (as Jeremie mentions). I personally store dates in UTC `moment(startDate).toISOString()` on the client you can `moment(startDate)` to work in [local date and time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Looking at the [Waterline source for deferred queries](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js) (see the `where` method) it applies the most recent `datetime_field` criteria it finds to be valid.

After trawling through code, searches and the group I didn't find anything that helped. I sure hope I've missed something obvious, but for now my current suggestion would be to anchor the results on your `startDate` and then cap it with a limit,

e.g.

```
.where({ datetime_field: { '>=': startDate } })
.limit(100)
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to format your date as a string in the YYYY-MM-DD format.
If you need help formatting your dates, [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) has a lot of cool features for that.

formating your date would look something like

```
var formatedStartDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```